# Error launching activity from fragment android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have MainActivity with 3 fragments in it, and I want to switch to Activity2 from one of the fragments in MainActivity but my attempts always fail. My app crashes when I press the button ok in the third fragment to connect me to Activity2. I am working on a code I found in one tutorial. Thank you in advance!

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tv_name,tv_email,tv_message;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private AppCompatButton btn_change_password,btn_logout, btn_ok;
    private EditText et_old_password,et_new_password;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private ProgressBar progress;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        tv_name.setText("Здравей, "+pref.getString(Constants.NAME,"")+"!");
        tv_email.setText(pref.getString(Constants.EMAIL,""));
        btn_ok=(AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

    private void initViews(View view){

        tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        btn_change_password = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chg_password);
        btn_logout = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btn_ok=(AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btn_change_password.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn_chg_password:
                showDialog(); //I deleted this method from the code, it doesnt have a lot in common with my question
                break;
            case R.id.btn_logout:
                logout();
                break;
}

    private void logout() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false);
        editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,"");
        editor.putString(Constants.NAME,"");
        editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID,"");
        editor.apply();
        goToLogin();
    }

    private void goToLogin(){

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
        ft.commit();
    }


}
```

Comment: what's the error you get ,have you declared  activity2 in the manifest ?

Comment: can u show R.layout.fragment_profile ?

Comment: your fragment already implements onclick listener add this on switch condition 
`case R.id.btn_logout:
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add getActivity as context before startActivity()
also add NewTask Flag.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), activity2.class);
intent.addflags(intent.flag_activity_new_task);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Victoria so send Error Logs there might be another reason for crashing.

Comment: Thank you I managed to find my mistake and it was not in your code, it was in the activity2.class and everything worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You could not call method  `goToLogin()`  in fragment, you need to call in your activity contain this fragment because your fragment doesn't contain  layout `fragment_frame`, it 's in your activity.

If you want to call this method in your fragment, you move method `goToLogin()` to yourActivity and call in your fragment like this:

```
if(getActivity() instanceOf yourActivity) {
       ((youActivity) getActivity()).goToLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could happen because you didn't register the Activity2 in AndroidManifest.xml.

But to communicate from **Fragment** to **Activity**, you should use the MainActivity as the gate for it. Though it looks like a bit overkill, but it will ease your maintenance for a bigger project in the future.

You can use **interface** for this.

In your ProfileFragment define and create an interface:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    OnProfileListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnProfileListener {
        public void onProfileButtonOkClicked();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnProfileListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnProfileListener");
        }
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Then call the interface in your button click method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    btn_ok=(AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.onProfileButtonOkClicked();
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Finally, you need to implement the interface to your MainActivity:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements ProfileFragment.OnProfileListener{
    ...

    // When button ok in ProfileFragment clicked, this method will be called.
    public void onProfileButtonOkClicked() {
        // we can call the Activity here now.
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

For more details, read [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

---

**UPDATE**

For deprecated `onAttach()` in API Level >= 23, you can use the following code instead:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnProfileListener) {
        mCallback = (OnProfileListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnProfileListener");
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that onAttach is deprecated when I use Activity. When I try to use Context, my app crashes on start maybe because it is API16 while Context requires API23. I got totally puzzled...help me please

Comment: @Victoria: I've updated the code. The onAttach() method is deprecated by the android team in API Level >= 23.

Comment: Thank you but I finally managed to cope with this problem simply by using getActivity() instead of this in Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity2.class);